# How to achieve this menu layout? With full-height borders and the dropdown-menu properly aligned with the menu border bottom?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a menu like below, where:

- the border-bottom of the menu is next to the orange background without any white space, and this border-bottom occupy the full-width, without any white space at left or right
- the logo have a full height border right and and each menu item also have 
  full-height borders
- Also the "Item" that has a dropdown menu i want that when is open it is aligned with the gray border-bottom of the navbar.

[image]

For that im using the code below, but Im not achieving this layout, I have a working example with the layout Im getting "http://jsfiddle.net/4606qqux/". Do you know how to fix the code to achieve the above layout?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
    <a href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_nav" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="menu_container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_nav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto d-flex align-items-lg-center">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 0</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Jan
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit Profile</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">logout</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom:1px solid gray;
}

div.dropdown-menu {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

section {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-item {
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
}

.navbar{
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}
.logo{
  border-right:1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: What border width are you after?

Comment: Im using border of 1px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood this is what you are after:

```
.logo {
  border-right:1px solid gray;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4606qqux/1/

Here is an even-more-updated-fiddle without padding around the top navigation element:
http://jsfiddle.net/4606qqux/2/

Comment: Thanks. But its not equal, for example in the image the gray border-bottom of the menu is next/sticked to the orange background without any white space. And this border bottom in the image occupy the full width, there is no white space at left and right. Also the borders of the logo and menu items are not with full height like the image, there is some white space above the menu items.

Comment: How could one understand from the initial starting thread what you just said? Please update the initial thread and I will help you out.